# Having a "ValueError: could not convert string to float:" while using a Python dictionary

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to copy a string into a dictionary consisting of floats. I tried to change the dictionaries value into a string before copying. It did not work. I broke the problem down into the following code:

```
tst_dict = {}

tst_dict['name'] = np.zeros((2,3))

tst_dict['name'][0,0] = str(tst_dict['name'][0,0])
tst_dict['name'][0,0] = 'Hase'
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Hase'

Thanks for helping.

Comment: That is a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` of 2x3

Comment: Right, I need mainly floats and later decided that it would be nice to add a string for naming reasons.

Comment: I added those cases in my answer below, see if it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dtype=object`, you get an array of python object references. So you can have all the behaviors of python strings:

```
import numpy as np

tst_dict = {}
tst_dict['name'] = np.zeros((2,3), dtype=object)
tst_dict['name'][0,0] = str(tst_dict['name'][0,0])
tst_dict['name'][0,0] = 'Hase'

print(tst_dict)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'name': array([['Hase', 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)}
```

**EDIT**:

Using `dtype='<U1'` For a single `char` in the `str`:

```
import numpy as np

tst_dict = {}
tst_dict['name'] = np.zeros((2,3), dtype='<U1')
tst_dict['name'][0,0] = str(tst_dict['name'][0,0])
tst_dict['name'][0,0] = 'Hase'

print(tst_dict)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'name': array([['H', '', ''],
       ['', '', '']], dtype='<U1')}
```

Comment: Thanks, `dtype=object` was the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your array expects numbers. `np.zeros` data type by default is `float64`. If you want to have a string array specifiy it during creation (either `dtype=object` or `dtype='<Ux'`, with x number of characters). More info on string arrays [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html):

```
tst_dict = {}

tst_dict['name'] = np.zeros((2,3), dtype='<U10')
# if you want a string array
tst_dict['name'][0,0] = str(tst_dict['name'][0,0])
tst_dict['name'][0,0] = 'Hase'
```

Comment: That will only put `H` and not the rest of the `str`

Comment: I only need the first value of the array to be a string. The others are going to be floats in my workflow.

Comment: Then use `dtype=object`

Comment: Thanks, `dtype=object` was the solution I was looking for.